# How can I store static data to be available for both Reactor and minions?

Tags: salt-stack

I wish to store my slack api key so that it will be accessible from both Reactor states as well as states executed by minions (such as when running a highstate):

```
slack_api_key: xxx
```

If I add the data to a pillar, it can only be accessible from minions executing states:

```
{{ salt['pillar.get']('slack_api_key') }}
```

If I add the data to the master config, it can only be accessible from the Reactor:

```
{{ opts['slack_api_key'] }}
```

How can I store this data and be able to access it from both the Reactor and from states included in my highstate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to set the following in the `master` configuration:

```
# The pillar_opts option adds the master configuration file data to a dict in
# the pillar called "master". This is used to set simple configurations in the
# master config file that can then be used on minions.
pillar_opts: True

# Slack API key
slack_api_key: 'xxx'
```

Then any data in the `master` configuration can be accessed like this...

From minions:

```
{{ salt['pillar.get']('master:slack_api_key') }}
- or - 
{{ pillar['master']['slack_api_key'] }}
```

From Reactor:

```
{{ opts['slack_api_key'] }}
```

However, this is not a great answer, as *any* data in the `master` configuration is now exposed to minions.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using sdb for this.

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/sdb/